# nodejs not compiling unimported files, even if such files are referenced in a runtime require

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am importing my files using `require(path + ".js")` where `path` is a variable specified at runtime. Since the files specified in `path` are not referenced explicitly at compile-time, it seems that node.js is not compiling them and they are not included in the `.build` directory. Therefore, the line `require(path + ".js")` fails.

Adding an unused import statement such as `import file from "file.ts"` at the top of my main file causes node.js to compile them as a ".js" file and consequently the line `require(path + ".js")` succeeds.

Unfortunately, I do not want to add an unused import statement for the purposes of triggering a compiler action, as that defeats the purpose of the increased flexibility provided by using require with a runtime variable.

Can I set a property in package.json or elsewhere such that all files within a directory tree are compiled and placed into the `.build` folder?

Comment: Have you tried `"include": ["./**/*.ts"]`?

Comment: @dx_over_dt I just did, and it's not including the unimported files.